# How to find the basics of WordPress Custom Portfolio Functionality

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, portfolio

I'm looking for some help in determining the basic building blocks of a very common type of custom portfolio I've been seeing in many WordPress themes lately. Namely, it's an animation of the portfolio items when the "category" is selected.

To see what I mean, have a look at two themes that have this:
http://themes.kubasto.com/website/portfolio/portfolio-small-one/
http://themes.pixelwars.org/responsy/portfolio.html

This functionality is so similar between the two, that I have to believe that there is some common core of code that runs them both, but I can't seem to find it!

Does anyone have any insight into what runs these both? Or how this feature could be replicated?

Thanks so much for your help.

-Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple jQuery plug-ins for that. The most common on is Masonry. But there is also one I like better (because is much more lighter and fitted my basic needs) called Wookmark (http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

First one is using Dave DeSandro's jquery Masonry and the second is using it's big brother Isotope with filters.

You can see all the documentation for it at http://www.metafizzy.co

I'd recommend just buying isotope, it's a great bit of work and the documentation and examples make it easy to get to grips with. There are a few threads on Stackoverflow that the author has helped out with too.